# My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists doesnt work [vb.net]

Tags: vb.net, file-exists

I cant understand why i cant find files, its on right location. It was working before. But now it works only for certain files in the same location. Im 100% sure that the path and name of the file is the same as in the code.... Can't understand while i cant find the files...

```
 If ComboBox2.Text = "  1YZ-C01C 567.737.061 CA" Then
        If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("source/Chr/1YZ-C01C 567.737.061-eeprom.txt") Then
            If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("source/Chrysler/1YZ-C01C 567.737.061-erom.txt") Then
                Button2.Enabled = False
                button1.Enabled = False 
        Else
            ErrorOops.Show()
            Button2.Enabled = True
            Label1.Text = "Cant Find the file."
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Else
            ErrorOops.Show()
            Button2.Enabled = True
            Label1.Text = "Cant Find the file."
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to supply the full path.
`("source/Chr/1YZ-C01C 567.737.061-eeprom.txt")` is not the full path.

Use:

```
Path.Combine(Path, File)
```

So in your example File would be:
`"1YZ-C01C 567.737.061-eeprom.txt"`
and the full path (starting with C: D: or whatever) to `"source/Chr"`

Typical Example:

```
dim MyPath as string = "C:\MyData\source\Chr"
dim MyPath as string = Application.StartupPath & "\source\Chr" 'Alternative
dim MyFile as string = "1YZ-C01C 567.737.061-eeprom.txt"
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Path.Combine(MyPath,MyFile)) then
...
end if
```

Comment: no, source/Chr/1YZ-C01C 567.737.061-eeprom.txt - means that soruce folder on the same path with .exe file

Comment: I edited above answer to give example. However, I think I may have misinterpreted the original question so please ignore if irrelevant. Is you path on a network?

Comment: When you run a debug on the application, the application folder is ./bin/Debug . So your file path would be <project folder>/bin/Debug/source/Chr/1YZ-C01C 567.737.061-eeprom.txt .

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide a full path. When the file is in the same folder as your application then you can use `Application.StartupPath` for it. So it would look like this:

```
If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(Application.StartupPath & "/source/Chr/1YZ-C01C 567.737.061-eeprom.txt") Then
```

If your application path is for example C:\test then the result is: `C:\test/source/Chr/1YZ-C01C 567.737.061-eeprom.txt`